# Filer an array of objects with yq

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a yaml file that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
entries:
  blue-green-toggle:
  - description: Used to toggle an application between blue and green
    name: blue-green-toggle
    version: 1.0.17
    apiVersion: v2
  - description: Used to toggle an application between blue and green
    name: blue-green-toggle
    version: 1.0.16
    apiVersion: v2
  - description: Used to toggle an application between blue and green
    name: blue-green-toggle
    version: 1.0.15
    apiVersion: v2
  istio-config:
  - description: Used to configure the cluster level settings of istio.
    name: istio-config
    version: 1.0.4
    apiVersion: v2
  - description: Used to configure the cluster level settings of istio.
    name: istio-config
    version: 1.0.1
    apiVersion: v2
  latest-toggle:
    name: latest-toggle
    version: 1.0.5
    apiVersion: v2
  standard-helm-chart:
    name: standard-helm-chart
    version: 1.1.10
    apiVersion: v2
    name: standard-helm-chart
    version: 2.0.1
    apiVersion: v2
    name: standard-helm-chart
    version: 1.0.34
    apiVersion: v2
    name: standard-helm-chart
    version: 1.0.10
    apiVersion: v2
    name: standard-helm-chart
    version: 1.0.9
    apiVersion: v2
generated: 2021-06-22T00:22:33.1554922Z
...
```

I am trying to list the the `version` numbers that start with `1.0.` and are listed in the `standard-helm-chart` section.

I have used this so far to get just the entries for the `standard-helm-chart`:

```
yq eval '.entries | .standard-arup-helm-chart' index.yaml
```

That worked fine.  So then I then tried to get just to the rows with `version` matching `1.0.*`.  I read over the [select documentation](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/select) for `yq`, but it does not indicate how to match when you are looking at an object instead of just a string.

I tried this:

```
yq eval '.entries | .standard-arup-helm-chart | select(. == "1.0.*")' index.yaml
```

But this fails.  And I would expect it to, because it can't compare the string of "1.0.*" to the whole object.

I also tried:

```
yq eval '.entries | .standard-arup-helm-chart | select(.version == "1.0.*")' index.yaml
```

Thinking that would let `yq` know that I want to just look at the version.  But it said `Error: Cannot index array with 'version'`

I then figured I needed to try an array style syntax:

```
yq eval '.entries | .standard-arup-helm-chart | select(.[version] == "1.0.*")' index.yaml
```

But that fails with a parsing error.

**What command can I send `yq` to get all the version numbers that start with `1.0.`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Took some trial an error, but this is what I ended up with:

```
yq eval '.entries.standard-helm-chart.[] | select(.version == "1.0.*") | .version' index.yaml
```